# Case insensitive f key in vim?

Tags: vim

Does anyone know of any way to get the 'f' key in vim normal command mode to operate case insensitive

Example

```
function! OpenCurrentFileInMarked()
```

In the above line, if I am at the start of the line I want to be able to type 'fi'and get the first 'i' and then ';' to toggle to the capital 'I' in the middle of the function name. I would prefer that the 'f' key is always bound to case insensitivity. Would work much better for me as a default.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the `;` key in combination with `f`. Didn't even know that one ;).

Comment: See also the Q/A on vi.SE: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15382/how-to-make-fchar-case-insensitive

Answer (score 4):

The easy answer here is: use a plugin. Others have had the idea before.

- > *[**Fanf,ingTastic;**](https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic): Find a char across lines*

  The main purpose of this plugin is to make `f` and `t` cross the line boundary.

  To make them ignore case you need to `let g:fanfingtastic_ignorecase = 1` in your vimrc.
- > *[**ft_improved**](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3877): improved f/t command*

  Same here.

  To make it ignore case you again need to set a variable in your vimrc, this time `let g:ft_improved_ignorecase = 1`.

Comment: Here is one more: [vim-extended-ft](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4726). I prefer it because i managed to use custom keys instead of f/t with it.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of this (case insensitive <kbd>f</kbd>) is actually in the reference manual as an example of how to use the `getchar()` function:

> This example redefines "f" to ignore case:
>
> ```
> :nmap f :call FindChar()<CR>
> :function FindChar()
> :  let c = nr2char(getchar())
> :  while col('.') < col('$') - 1
> :    normal l
> :    if getline('.')[col('.') - 1] ==? c
> :      break
> :    endif
> :  endwhile
> :endfunction
> ```

See `:help getchar()`.

You'll need to save the character returned and write a similar map for <kbd>;</kbd> if you want that to work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with regular vim commands.  However, you can [write your own function](https://superuser.com/a/303594/1542) and bind the <kbd>f</kbd> key to it.

Comment: Note: Only making a function for the `f` command will cripple part of the `;` and `,` commands.

Comment: I pinged the writer on https://github.com/rhysd/clever-f.vim because case insensitivity with their functionality would be great because: 1) I remapped ; to : to have easier access to command mode, and 2) they already messed with moving f,F,t,T to a function so it might be eay