# How to make f and t wrap around the current line in vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to make the 'f' and 't' command wrap around the line?  For example, if I have

`Hello, my name is _intz`,

where `_` denotes my cursor position, I would like to be able to press `fl` for vim to place my cursor on the first `l` on the line.

Similarly, I would ideally like the `,` and `;` commands to also wrap on the current line.

Thank you

Comment: I just want to check, are you aware of `F` and `T`? The capital letter versions of `f` and `t`? There isn't a simple option to change to achieve what you're asking for. I'm sure it could be achieved, but it's not worth doing.

Comment: Furthermore, you have `0` that brings you to the beginning of the line. In you example, you would just hit `0fl`. However, you could get some better answer on [vi & Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @doopNudles Yes I am!  The reason that I'm asking is I'll often search for characters that are capital letters, and I end up mixing up something like ```fP``` for ```FP``` or something similar.   I mistype this often enough, so ideally it would be nice to reconfigure ```f``` or ```F```.

Comment: @intz, then just take your time to correct/improve your touchtyping, no?

Comment: @Enlico Thanks for the suggesting about ```0```.  And sure, I can go ask over there as well.

Comment: @intz Well it's good you're aware of them. I'm pretty sure you could hack together some vimscript to achieve what you want, but it wouldn't be worth it

Comment: I think cross-posting is not encouraged. Maybe you can post there (include the more info we have provided) and delete this?

Comment: If the problem is that you are mixing up capital letters, then you can set the `Ff` / `Ft` search to be case-insensitive.  That way, you can focus on whether you want `F` or `f`, and not worry about whether it is `p` or `P` (in your example).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280247/case-insensitive-f-key-in-vim  and  https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15382/how-to-make-fchar-case-insensitive  have suggestions.

Comment: Since an answer was already posted before I was able to delete this post, I decided to keep it up, and then post an answer that I was looking for that was obtained with help from the vim stack exchange.  If there is better etiquette, feel free to let me know

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible without implementing the feature yourself.

Note that `fF` are universally expected to mean "next on the line" and `tT` to mean "previous on the line", both of which being extremely useful in their own right. Instead of changing their meaning, and thus reducing the overall usefulness of Vim, you should consider making *new* commands.

Something like these quick and dirty mappings:

```
" move the cursor on first occurrence of character on the line
nnoremap <expr> <key> '0f' . nr2char(getchar())

" move the cursor before first occurrence of character on the line
nnoremap <expr> <key> '0t' . nr2char(getchar())
```

See `:help <expr>`, `:help nr2char()`, `:help getchar()`.

Comment: Is that second mapping supposed to be `'0F'`? I don't see what that would do.

Comment: It was supposed to be `0t`. Not sure how that `F` found its way there. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this answer https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/29167/determine-if-there-is-a-matching-character-on-the-current-line-past-the-cursor, the following maps `<c-f>` to allow that gives it the functionality of `f` with same line wrapping.

```
function!Neweff()
        let character = nr2char(getchar())
        let beforejump = getpos('.')
        execute 'norm! f'.character.''
        let afterjump = getpos('.')
        if beforejump == afterjump
            let firstcharacter = getline(".")[0]
            execute 'norm! 0'
            if character !=# firstcharacter
                execute 'norm! f'.character.''
            endif
        endif
endfunction

nnoremap <c-f> :call Neweff()<CR>
```